# How to get the metadata of of a soql results query with no records returned?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am new to Salesforce and I use Java Salesforce API (e.g.,  com.sforce.soap.metadata,com.sforce.ws). I know how to query through Java code using soql syntax.

At times, the soql does not return results, which makes it impossible to get details about the fields of the results, so I have need to get metadata on soql query  regardless whether results are returned. If I have the following soql:

```
SELECT Name FROM Position_c WHERE Id NOT IN SELECT Position__c FROM Job_Application__c)
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use Java to get the metadata on such query even if the query returns zero results ?  It would be nice if you could include a short snippet of code showing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get it out of a 0 rows query. However you can look at the metadata for any object using the describesObject.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm

Comment: The soql statements will be used to get query results which will be translated to sql tables; hence the need to create sql table even when no records are returned.  The soql statements are provided by user and therefore can be anything.  Therefore, to use the technique you mentioned, it will be necessary to parse the soql statement and find the objects involved -- which is one MAJOR task to accomplish.  We are really talking about so-called soql engine parser/  Not an easy task to accomplish.  I would prefer to leave that option as last resort.